# How to deal with popups for clusters in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I have an openlayers map which generates points from an array as vector features, with popups for these features, which works fine. Since I have so many points on this map, I have started working with cluster strategy. I can get the popups working fine on the points using the cluster strategy, but only the nonclustered points. I can get the popup to show the info for the first point of the cluster, but what I want to be able to do is have the popup display the info for each feature in the cluster, possibly with pagination or arrows that will allow the user to go through each.

I have seen olwidget and i like the way it handles popups, but I can't seem to find any example of how to get it working with an existing map/layer, if possible.
Is there a solution? I would prefer to use olwidget because i like the fact that the popups are styled with css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example from openlayers shows how to access the information from each feature in the cluster.  http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/strategy-cluster.html

This should be enough to get you started.  You basically can just take the output div in the bottom and make it a popup and feed that data straight in.

Comment: i ended up solving the issue a different way, but i could see this as a solution